# How to use swagger to send POST request as text/html through body

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, swagger

I cant get swagger to send a POST request as plain text. I am new to this, can someone help me out!

```
/**
 * @swagger
 * /:
 *  post:
 *    summary: Use to validate your text for bla bla format
 *    description: Request is sent through body as text/html
 *    requestBody:
 *      required: true
 *      content:
 *        text/plain:
 *          schema:
 *            type: string
 *    responses:
 *      200:
 *        description: Validated
 */
```

Comment: How are you sending a POST request (e.g. through curl, Swagger UI, or in some other way) and what exactly is not working? What result do you expect and what is the actual result?

Comment: I am sending the request by the swagger UI, I think I should see an input on the UI for sending the request but I cant figure out how to make that work.

Comment: _"I think I should see an input on the UI for sending the request"_ - can you post a screenshot of the current UI? If an input for the request body is missing, it might be caused by incorrect code annotations or incorrect indentation of the annotations.

Comment: I solved the issue, thank you for the efforts though.